# three dots on round-slider

Tags: javascript, round-slider

I am trying to figure out the way to add not **two** but three dots/handles on a round slider (here: https://roundsliderui.com/document.html#options)

According to the documentation number of possible handles  is defined by `sliderType` option which can be either `default` or `min-range` or `range`  - the last one defines two handles instead of one.

Any advice how to handle (pun not intended) is welcome.

Comment: How exactly would 3 handles work? I can't quite imagine it

Comment: I need a user to divide a range of 100% into three parts. My plan is to ask them to drop three dots on a circle and then ask them to drag them based on their preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [**roundSlider**](https://roundsliderui.com/) by default it have one or two handles only. If you want to add multiple handles then you can achieve it by some customization. Check the below demo:

#### [`DEMO 1`](https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/yzt9wn0e/)

In addition, based on your requirement I have the below suggestion for you. If you want to divide the circle into 3 pieces then you can do it with 2 handles itself. Check the below demo:

#### [`DEMO 2`](https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/b2zt7yvf/1/)

[image: round slider with multiple handles]